# flat dictionary from structured text using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to create a dictionary from a piece of structured text, but I can't wrap my head around the correct syntax.

```
text = 'english (fluently), spanish (poorly)'

# desired output: 
{english: fluently, spanish: poorly}

# one of my many attempts: 
dict((language,proficiency.strip('\(\)')) for language,proficiency in lp.split(' ') for lp in text.split(', '))

# but resulting error: 
NameError: name 'lp' is not defined
```

I guess that **lp** in **lp.split(' ')** is not defined, but I can't figure out, how to rework the syntax to get the desired result.

In reality, the scenario is more complex. I have a dataframe and I am aiming to eventually use a function to tidy the aforementioned data into columns for each individual language and columns for each corresponding proficiency. Something like below (although it probably can be done way more efficiently)

```
# pandas dataframe
pd.DataFrame({'language': ['english, spanish (poorly)', 'turkish']})
        
# desired output: 
pd.DataFrame({'Language: English': [True, False], 'Language proficiency: English': ['average', pd.NA], 'Language: Spanish': [True, False], 'Language proficiency: Spanish': ['poorly', pd.NA], 'Language: Turkish': [False, True], 'Language proficiency: Turkish': [pd.NA, 'average']})
    
# my attempt
def tidy(content):
    if pd.isna(content):
        pass
    else:
        dict((language,proficiency.strip('\(\)')) for language,proficiency in lp.split(' ') for lp in text.split(', '))

def tidy_language(language, content):
    if pd.isna(content):
        return pd.NA
    else:
        if language in content.keys():
            return True
        else:
            return False

def tidy_proficiency(language, content):
    if pd.isna(content):
        return pd.NA
    else:
        if language in content.keys():
            return content.language
        else:
            return pd.NA

languages = ['english', 'spanish', 'turkish']
df['language'] = df['language'].map(lambda x: tidy(x))
for language in languages:
    df['Language: {}'.format(language.capitalize())] = df['language'].map(lambda x: tidy_language(language, content)
    df['Language proficiency: {}'.format(language.capitalize())] =  df['language'].map(lambda x: tidy_proficiency(language, content)
```

Comment: first you have to split `text` on comma - `items = text.split(",")`  - and later every item you have to split on space `for lp in items: language,proficiency = lp.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick solution. Feed the text to the function.

```
def text_to_dict(text):
    text=text+" "

    new=""
    for alphabet in text:
        if alphabet=="," or alphabet=="(" or alphabet==")":
            continue;
        new+=alphabet

    lis=[]
    temp=""
    for alphabet in new:
        if alphabet==" ":
            if temp[0]==" ":
                temp=temp[1:len(temp)]
            lis.append(temp)
            temp=""
        temp+=alphabet

    dict={}
    for el in lis:
        if lis.index(el)%2==0:
            dict[el]=lis[lis.index(el)+1]

    return dict

if __name__=="__main__":
    text="english (fluently), spanish (poorly), bangla (fluently)"
    print(text_to_dict(text))
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to reverse the two `for` loops in the list comprehension (`for` loops need to appear in the same order as if you are writing imperative code).
2. You don't need backslashes in `.strip('\(\)')`.
3. `for language,proficiency in lp.split(' ')` will try to *unpack* each item of `lp.split(' ')` to the tuple `(language,proficiency)`, therefore, wrap `lp.split(' ')` into a 1-element list to achieve what you want:

```
dict((l,p.strip('()')) for lp in text.split(', ') for l,p in [lp.split(' ')])
```

> {'english': 'fluently', 'spanish': 'poorly'}

The above can be written as a `dict`-comprehension:

```
{l: p.strip('()') for lp in text.split(', ') for l,p in [lp.split(' ')]}
```

which reads a bit better.

An alternative approach using `re`:

```
import re
dict(re.findall(r'(\w+) \((\w+)\),?', text))
```

> {'english': 'fluently', 'spanish': 'poorly'}

Answer (score 1):

Although [fferri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1044117/fferri) provides some perfect solutions to my original question, my final solution in the context of the dataframe resembles more the suggestion of [SuperNoob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14385310/supernoob).

My final solution:

```
# Create a parser function to form a dictionary of language: proficiency pairs from the values in the 'Speaks' column.
def parse_dictionary(content):
    if pd.isna(content):
        pass
    else:
        d = {}
        lps = content.split(', ')
        for lp in lps:
            if '(' not in lp:
                l = lp
                p = pd.NA
            else:
                l, p = lp.split('(')
                l = l.strip().capitalize()
                p = p.strip('()')
            d[l] = p
        return d
    
# Create a parser function to return the languages fom the dictionary in the 'Speaks' column.    
def parse_language(language, d):      
    if pd.isna(d):
        pass
    else:
        if language in d.keys():
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
# Create a parser function to return the language proficiencies fom the dictionary in the 'Speaks' column.
def parse_proficiency(language, d):   
    if pd.isna(d):
        pass
    else:
        if language in d.keys():
            return d[language]
        else:
            return pd.NA

# Parse the values in the 'Speaks' column to create a dictionary of language: proficiency pairs.
df['Speaks'] = df['Speaks'].map(lambda x: parse_dictionary(x))  

# Parse the values in the 'Speaks' column to create seperate 'language' columns with True-False values.
for language in languages:
    df['Language: {}'.format(language)] = df['Speaks'].apply(lambda d: parse_language(language, d))

# Parse the values in the 'Speaks' column to create seperate 'Language proficiency' columns with proficiency values.
for language in languages:
    df['Language proficiency: {}'.format(language)] = df['Speaks'].apply(lambda d: parse_proficiency(language, d))
```